# How to add a next element to a grid

Tags: c#, uwp

I know that I can chose a row and column with

```
Grid.SetRow(Box, i);
Grid.SetColumn(Box, j);
```

But that's not what I want. I want to create a window where the user can pick out of a selection of files. It should look like if you go to the explorer and change the view to icons. I can't just set a row and column, because the window can be resized. Then the children need to reudjust their position.

Using a grid is what I would do on Android, but maybe there exists a better solution in UWP that I don't know of.

Comment: Can you use warp panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/listview-and-gridview) and utilize [data binding](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-040-Data-Binding-to-the-GridView-and-ListView-Controls).